# size of (array) argument

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, size

I have a code which finds the size of input using the following way:

```
template <typename T>
void func (T& input) {
    const void *valuePtr;
    size_t valueSize;
    tie(valuePtr, valueSize)
            = detail::ParamInfo<typename remove_const<T>::type>::get(input);
    //code
}
```

If input is an array I need to get its actual size not the pointer size.
Thus if I have

```
size_t data[3];
```

and I call `func` with data param, I indeed get `valueSize = 12`
But if I don`t know the size of array I encounter a problem,for example:
If I have

```
vector<size_t> data;
data = getData(); //as a result data is a vector of 2 elements
size_t *dataArr = &data[0];
```

if I call `func` with `dataArr` param, I get 4,instead of 8.

How can I solve this - I can't know/predict the size of parameter returned from `getData()`

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Given just a pointer, there is no portable way to know if it points to a single object or an array of objects. The vector `data` knows its size but not the pointer `dataArr`.

Answer (score 0):

You could not obtain size of dynamic array in compile time. You need to do it in runtime passing vector size as function parameter, make overload for it:

```
template <typename T> void func(T& input, size_t i_size);
```

Or better make overload for `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T> void func(std::vector<T>& input);
// Use input.size() to get array size
```